# Creating Fill Color in Arrowhead - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create a graphic style that looks like "A", applicable to a stroke.

I can get "B" using the stroke panel, with arrowhead options, but I'm not able to control the stroke weight of the circle or the fill color...

Ideas? Thanks

[image: img]

Comment: I don't really get the question. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi billythekid, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Are you making the circle and arrow separately? It might be easier to just draw the circle and then group an arrow with the circle.

Comment: AndrewH: Now I build them separate and then and group  them, yes. But I want it to be an applicable style to any stroke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to customize arrowheads, but it is quite daunting. If you are going to use the custom arrowhead all the time it would make sense to create a custom one. For only one time uses, I would not suggest it.

But since you asked...

From [Adobe's help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stroke-object.html#customize_arrowheads)

> **Customize arrowheads**
>
> To define custom arrowheads, open the Arrowheads.ai file, which is
>   located under ShowPackageContent\Required\Resources\\ (for
>   Mac) and \Support Files\Required\Resources\\ (for Windows).
>   Follow the instructions in the file to create custom arrowheads.
>
> Place the updated Arrowheads.ai file at: \Plug-ins\
>   and avoid replacing the existing Arrowheads.ai file.

The Arrowheads.ai file has very detailed instructions about how to create the arrowheads.

Now, last but not least...

**How did I come up with this answer**

- Went to Google.com (any other search engine would work).
- Searched for "adobe illustrator customize arrowhead". The less and the more precise the terms are, the better.
- Scanned down the list of results and noticed one of the links was from adobe.com. Clicked on it because, if the answer is in adobe's help files, then there is no point in searching around anymore.

Comment: @billythekid you should be aware that even if you do create a custom arrowhead, you are not going to be able to control the stroke and fill of that circle in the arrowhead form. The arrowheads are not independently controlled beyond scale.

Comment: Thanks cockypup. I will be using it quite a bit for annotating docs, so yes it's worth the effort. I had found that adobe help doc exactly how you did, but was simply curious if someone had an individual workaround, or other tip, etc. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I would create the 2 objects separately. For web, the circle is ~72px with a 1.5 pt stroke. Use the eye drop tool (I) to get the colors.

[image: circle]

Stroke options for the line extending from the circle

[image: stroke line]

result

[image: result]

You can then group the 2 objects together or combine then with the path finder. You can also expand the shapes.

Comment: Thanks AndrewH. I've been doing this for a while, I was simply trying to find a way to do it through a single graphic style. Looks like the only option is to customize an arrowhead entirely.